# AngularJS not loading in pages of PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-desktop-app

I am able to get the Angular Controller working on the index.html page, but its not loading on any of the other pages.
My index page is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myPhonegapApp">
<head>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/my-angscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="views">
        <div class="view view-main">
             <div class="pages navbar-through toolbar-through">
                <div data-page="index" class="page">
                    <div class="page-content">
                        <div class="content-block">
                            <a href="mypage1.html">My Page1</a> <br>
                            <a href="mypage2.html">My Page2</a> <br>

                            <div ng-controller="myAngController">
                                <p>The name is : {{name}}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/framework7/js/framework7.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/my-app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I linked mypage1.html from the index page and the code for mypage1.html is exactly same as index.html and only this part is changed: `<div data-page="mypage1" class="page">`

Now the my-angscript.js is:

```
var app = angular.module("myPhonegapApp", []);

app.controller("myAngController", function($scope){

    $scope.name = "Johnny Doe";
});
```

The code works fine on the index page. But when I go to mypage1.html, it does not work. It only shows `{{name}}`. What am I doing wrong?

**PhoneGap :** v6.4.3 
**AngularJS:** v1.6.1

Comment: try to assign the controller `<div ng-controller="myAngController" data-page="mypage1" class="page">`

Comment: It did not make any difference. Still not displaying.